# Sort array in alphabetical order : Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array say `myArray = ["Manu","Anju","Zamya","Bijoy"]`

How can i sort this array in alphabetical order using `coffeescript`?

Expected Output : `myArray = ["Anju","Bijoy","Manu","Zamya"]`

Comment: `myArray.sort()` isn't working?

Comment: I didn't knew about this function. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't see a problem, this is same as js `sort` function: `myArray.sort()`